# I don't want to show console after execute my exe file

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd, web-crawler, pyinstaller

I made web Crawler with Python.

And then, change the Crawler_file.py into Crawler_file.exe with Pyinstaller!

```
pyinstaller -F -w Crawler_file.py
```

Though it worked well, the console page(cmd) is still existed on my page

I tried to remove that console page with following ways.

1. Add quit() function after python code

   sys.exit()
2. Make bat file to run my Crawler
   but the console page are still exist even though my crawler has already done
3. Use 'start' function in bat file.
   when I use bat file to execute my crawler..

- The console is opened (bat)
- the opened console open my crawler console (exe)
- the first opened console is closed (bat)
- the crawler console is still opening... forever (exe)

I want to close the console opened when my crawler works end..

sorry for my English skills.. I need your help..

Comment: Are you using any statements to print in console. Any print statement ??

Comment: Yes I use print() function to test crawler working well

Comment: Print is a console command remove it and all those which are for console and rebuild, this would solve the problem.

Comment: Thx for Ur help!
However.. though there is no print() function, the console is still opened...